# filter grid data in extjs

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I want to use checkboxes in extjs to filter a grid. This is my checkbox

```
xtype: 'checkboxfield',
id: 'cb1',
boxLabel: 'Online',
checked: true,
handler: function (field, value) { }

xtype: 'checkboxfield',
id: 'cb2',
boxLabel: 'offline',
checked: true,
handler: function (field, value) { }
```

What i want is that when i select it it will filter my store. It should tell the store to show the online records and/or the offline records.

i read something about the Boolean filters so maybe that is something to use but i can't find out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use your store's filter method on your handler like

```
handler: function (field, value) { 
    store.filter('online', value);
}
```

Comment: how can i sort on more then one value? for example: store.filter('color', red & blue); ??

Comment: you can user store.filterBy method for more than one column or complex filtering. you can read documentation for usage http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy